# NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for #<Array:0x007f51c020bd18>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, nomethoderror

I am getting this error and using Rails 5.

> NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for #<Array:0x007f51cf4dc948>
>   app/controllers/traumas_controller.rb:99:in`trauma_params' 
>   app/controllers/traumas_controller.rb:25:in `create_multiple'

Controller params are as below.

> Started POST "/traumas/create_multiple" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-04
>   20:09:36 +0530 Processing by TraumasController#create_multiple as JS
>   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "fields"=>[{"contusions"=>"1", "burns"=>"",
>   "at_scene"=>"At Scene", "emergency_detail_id"=>"96",
>   "trauma_region"=>"Head-Back"}], "commit"=>"Submit"}

I am trying to create record as below in controller:

```
  def create_multiple
    trauma_params
    params[:fields].each do |values|
       u = Trauma.create(values)
    end
  end

def trauma_params
        params.require(:fields).permit(:fields => [])
end
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Kiran.

Comment: Do I understand right, that you intend to accept any array including the empty array for the :fields parameter? I believe that the .permit is not the right method to perform input validation. What happens, if you remove the .permit statement?

Answer (score 14):

Parameters:

```
{"fields"=>[{"contusions"=>"1", "burns"=>"", "at_scene"=>"At Scene", "emergency_detail_id"=>"96", "trauma_region"=>"Head-Back"}]}
```

Safelist array of objects, with the "fields" attribute required:

```
def trauma_params
  params.permit(fields: [
   :contusions,
   :burns,
   :at_scene,
   :emergency_detail_id,
   :trauma_region
  ])
  .require(:fields)
end
```

Source: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#nested-parameters

Answer (score 8):

I resolved it by referring this (https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/issues/140) github issue.

**EDIT**

For parameters like the following (which are in Array):

> Parameters: {"fields"=>[{"contusions"=>"1", "burns"=>"",
>   "at_scene"=>"At Scene", "emergency_detail_id"=>"96",
>   "trauma_region"=>"Head-Back"}], "commit"=>"Submit"}

We can do:

```
def trauma_params
  params.require(:fields).map do |p|
    ActionController::Parameters.new(p).permit(
      :contusions,
      :burns,
      :at_scene,
      :emergency_detail_id,
      :trauma_region
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: I get `NoMethodError (undefined method 'with_indifferent_access' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x007f996827fac0>):' How do I solve this?
`

Comment: @JosephN. Rails 5 now returns `ActionController::Parameters` so there is no need for that call. The third line would now look like: `p.permit(`.

Comment: @craineum Now it is returning following error `ArgumentError (When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.):`

Comment: This is the code `params.require(:newParams).map do |p|
        p.permit(
          :value,
          :tag,
          :position
        )
      end` **newParams is an array**